# Beamer overlay and counter

Tags: beamer, counters, overlays

I have a counter that I want to use for the beamer `\onslide` command.

Using

```
\newcounter{coun}
%....
%
\onslide<\coun ->{ ....}
```

doesn't work. What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `\value{coun}` instead:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcounter{coun}

\setcounter{coun}{3}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Always here
\onslide<\value{coun} ->{on slide 3}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

In general, with LaTeX counters then `\value{<counter name>}` expands to the value of the counter.  The counter name itself is not a macro so there's some magic under the bonnet that links the counter name (in this case `coun`) with a macro that displays its value.

(**Note**: In the original, I had `\thecoun` in place of `\value{coun}`.  As Matthew pointed out in the comments, `\value{coun}` is the correct one to have here.)

Comment: Does `\value{coun}` work as well?  `\thecoun` can be redefined to give non-numeric renderings of the counter value.  But `\value{coun}` should always give the arabic value.

Comment: @Matthew: you are _absolutely_ right.  I'll change my answer.

Comment: Will Robertson reminded me of that a few days ago.  Though it's unlikely the OP would change `\thecoun` and get errors, it is "the LaTeX way."

Comment: (Missed one; edited again)