# Using counter for \onslide in tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I am trying to use a counter in the `tikzpicture` environment.
The counter needs to keep track of the slide from when the picture needs to be shown; that way, it is easy to add or delete a line.

```
    \documentclass{beamer}

    \usepackage{tikz}

    \begin{document}

    \newcounter{test}
    \addtocounter{test}{1}
    \begin{frame}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \onslide<\arabic{test}->{\draw (0,0)--(1,1);}
    \addtocountour{test}{1};
    \onslide<\arabic{test}->{\draw (1,1)--(2,0);}
    \addtocounter{test}{1};
    \onslide<\arabic{test}->{\draw (2,0)--(3,1);}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6607/21891

Comment: Though, I can’t really follow your example, it would be better to use `\value{test}` instead of `\arabic{test}`.

Comment: Can you please explain a little more the context? Otherwise, the necessity for a counter is not clear from your current example. You could simply say `\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \onslide<+->{\draw (0,0)--(1,1);}
    \onslide<+->{\draw (1,1)--(2,0);}
    \onslide<+->{\draw (2,0)--(3,1);}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}` without any manual counter manipulation.

Comment: @ Gonzalo Medina

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

A few problems with your code: you misspelled the first `\addtocounter` and wrote `\addtocountour` instead; also, as discussed in [Andrew Stacey's post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6607/21891), if you want to use the value of a counter inside overlay specifications such as `\onslide<...>`, you should use `\value` (not `\arabic`, like you did).

However, it seems that using `\onslide<\value{...}>` *within a `tikzpicture` environment* generates errors. I'm not sure why; other contributors will probably chime in and provide a more complete answer than mine is.

In the meantime, here's a workaround; it uses PGF integers (defined with the `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` command) instead of counters but produces the expected output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\pgfmathtruncatemacro\test{1}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \onslide<\test->{\draw (0,0)--(1,1);}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\test{\test+1}
    \onslide<\test->{\draw (1,1)--(2,0);}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\test{\test+1}
    \onslide<\test->{\draw (2,0)--(3,1);}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```