# Using \onslide in Tikz and pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, pgfplots, overlays

I am having trouble with using beamer's `\onslide` in TikZ and pgfplots. The issue I have encountered is that if I use `\onslide` then the specific parts of the picture I want to appear on a specific slide appear on all the slides in the frame.

Using `\only` works (I do not obtain the same error). However, I want to use `\onslide` because then the figure takes up the same space all the time.

The following example demonstrates my problem. It should run as follows: There is a curve and an x-axis (slide 1). Then a second curve is added (slide 2). Then the y-axis is added (slide 3). Then some text is added (slide 4). However, the picture on slide 1 when I run this is how it should look at slide 3. Having given this a lot of thought and google-powered effort, I have no idea what the issue could possibly be! ([This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131767/using-counter-for-onslide-in-tikzpicture) tex.SE question is relevant, but does not really resolve the issue, or tell me the underlying issue (which I would be interested to know).)

```
\documentclass{beamer} 

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A frame}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        every axis plot post/.append style={mark=none,domain=-3:3,samples=50,smooth},
        clip=false,
        axis y line=none,
        axis x line*=bottom,
        ymin=0,
        xtick=\empty,
]
\onslide<1->{%on all slides. Note: Changing this to \onslide<2-> does not change anything - all parts of the image occur on all slides.
    \addplot {x^2};
}
\onslide<2->{%on the 2nd slide and those coming after
    \addplot {x^2+1};
}
\onslide<3->{%on the 3rd slide and those coming after
    \draw (axis description cs:0.5,0) -- (axis description cs:0.5,1);
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}\end{figure}

\onslide<4->{%on the 4th slide and those coming after
Slide 4.
}
%
\end{frame}
%
\end{document}
```

Note: In reality, I want to do this in a minipage. So if you provide an alternative method then you might want to bear this in mind. Or not.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6632/is-it-possible-to-create-overlays-in-beamer-inside-pgfplots-graphics

Comment: Also relevant is the second part of the answer to [Beamer: column alignment with tikzpicture inside](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/80516/13304).

Comment: @Jubobs Yeah, that is what I was looking for (although it says that the problem is unsolvable...boo!). I had only just realised that the issue was definately with pgfplots when you commented!

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino Ah, right, yes, that works for the `addplot`s. However, it seems not to work for the `\draw`.

Comment: @user1729: you have to use `\draw[visible on=<>]...`. I'm pretty sure it works too ;)

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino That was my guess, but I got the following error. `! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/visible on' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.`

Comment: I think you have to define `visible on` manually. For example, see [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55806/mindmap-tikzpicture-in-beamer-reveal-step-by-step#55849).

Comment: Did you add the definition of the style? Take as a reference: [Mindmap tikzpicture in beamer (reveal step by step)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55806/mindmap-tikzpicture-in-beamer-reveal-step-by-step/55849#55849)

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino Yeah, I found that reference (and posted a comment about it seconds before yours!). Thanks for your help - it all works fine now.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino Do you want to answer this one, or could it be closed as a duplicate?

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: good point. I vote to close as duplicate.